# Use HTTP Request in auto update feature of Install4j

Tags: install4j

I managed to use the auto update feature of Intsall4J by setting URL of updates.xml. For testing I used server (to host Installer.exe and updates.xml) with anonymous access. It worked fine.

But now requirement is that server needs HTTP request with Authorization header.

Is it possible to use HTTP request with Authorization header in auto update feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP authentication is supported by downloads, the updater will ask the user for user name and password.

If you want to hard-code the login in the installer, you can add a "Run script" action to the startup node and execute

```
System.getProperty("serverAuthUser", "user name");
System.getProperty("serverAuthPassword", "password");
```

Comment: Actually server requires bearer tokens for authorization which has to be passed in "Authorization" header. Is it possible to pass "Authorization" header?

Comment: No, that is not supported.